# Pagination with many elements is incredibly slow in Mongoose and Keystone

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, pagination, keystonejs

Versions: Keystone v4

I have a Mongo database with >20k items. What I want is a paginator that would allow the user to quickly scroll through the Mongo database 25 elements at a time. Currently, this feature is implemented, but the server takes >40 seconds to return the results because it queries the entire (20k item) database. However, only 25 elements are displayed on a single page, so I feel like if it just fetches 25 results instead of 20k, it should be quicker. How could I implement this? I know about the `.limit()` function, but I can't seem to figure out pagination in keystone while using that.

Current Code:

```
var q = Items.model.find();
q.exec(function(err, newss) {
    console.log('There are %d', newss.length); // Prints out 20k number
    ...//skip

    locals.cnts = newss;

    // console.log(newss[0])

    locals.pagerr = pager({
        page: parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 1,
        perPage: 25,
        total: newss.length
    });

    locals.itemsss = locals.cnts.slice(
        locals.pagerr.first - 1,
        locals.pagerr.last
    );
                
    next();

})
```

In it's current implmentation, it takes >40 seconds to return the paginated results. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `model.find()` function you're using here is equivalent to the Mongoose [`find()` function](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find). As you're calling it without any filters, this code is **retrieving all 25k items from the database** each time it runs. This data is being transferred to the web server/node process where the body of your `function(err, newss) {...}` function is run. Only *then* are the 25 items you're after being extracted from the set.

Instead, if you want to use offset-based pagination like this, you should be using the [`query.limit()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) and [`query.skip()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip) functions. If you need to count the total items first, do so in a separate query using [`query.count()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-count).

I haven't tested this code (and it's been a while since I used Mongoose), but I think you want something like this:

```js
// Warning! Untested example code
Items.model.find().count(function (err, count) {
  console.log('There are %d', count);

  locals.pager = pager({
    page: parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 1,
    perPage: 25,
    total: count
  });

  Items.model.find()
    .skip(locals.pager.first)
    .limit(25)
    .exec(function(err, results) {
      locals.results = results;
      next();
    });
});
```

On a more general note – if you like Keystone and want to use Mongo, keep an eye on the [Keystone 6 updates](https://keystonejs.com/updates). Keystone 6 uses Prisma 2 as it's ORM layer and they [recently released support for Mongo](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/2.27.0). As soon as that functionality production ready, we'll be supporting it in Keystone too.

Comment: What if I wanted to sort by a field? For example, if a user clicked the sort button so that it would only see results whose names were either: John, Terry, or Larry, how would I do that? I mean something like this: 

`
var q = Items.model.find({name: "John"||"terry"||"Larry"});
`

Comment: @YourFavoriteIntern What you're describing isn't sorting, it's filtering. But yes, you should be able to apply filters in the `.find()` call as per the Mongoose docs linked above. Alternatively, if you actually do want to _sort_ the results, there's the `.sort()` function which can be chained in before `.exec()` – https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-sort